# Why isn't the code working (here) when I try to change values of a list using 'for' loop?

Tags: python

Let's say there's this random list:

```
st=['smthg','xyz','random','000','666']
```

I want to change the values of the indices 1 to 3 using this for loop:

```
for anythg in st:
      st[1:3]='whtevr'
```

The shell(IDLE) doesn't give any response to this and the commandline freezes (the cmdln, however, after interrupting the execution and typing in 'st', it starts displaying:

```
't','e','v','r','t','e','v','r','t','e','v','r','t','e','v','r','t','e','v',
```

endlessly,until one again presses ctrl+C ).

I know the correct way to execute that properly would be:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    st[i]='whtevr'
```

Still, I'm expecting an answer for why didn't the previous one work?
(a beginner question, still.)

*

Comment: You shouldn't modify the list you are iterating over. You should make a copy.

Comment: You're changing the list `st` while iterating over it, which is a red flag right from the start.  What's killing you is the assignment `st[1:3]='whtevr'`  Since `st[1:3]` is a list slice, it's treating `whtevr` as an iterable.  So it's replacing the two elements in the range 1:3 (i.e., elements 1 and 2) with the 6 elements `'w'`, `'h'`, `'t'`, `'e'`, `'v'`, `'r'`.  It then continues iterating, over and over, growing the list by 4 elements every time.  It can never end.

Comment: What you need to ask yourself is, what do you want the result to look like?  It isn't clear from the code or the description.

Comment: @Tom Karzes. I just wanted the result to look like what it might've looked like after using some replace function(which doesn't exist<for lists>).  Then, I kind of messed around(which resulted in this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list just keeps on increasing.

```
>>> st=['smthg','xyz','random','000','666']
>>> st[1:3]='whtevr'
>>> st
['smthg', 'w', 'h', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', '000', '666']
>>> st[1:3]='whtevr'
>>> st
['smthg', 'w', 'h', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', '000', '666']
>>> st[1:3]='whtevr'
>>> st
['smthg', 'w', 'h', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', '000', '666']
>>> st[1:3]='whtevr'
>>> st
['smthg', 'w', 'h', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', '000', '666']
>>> st[1:3]='whtevr'
>>> st
['smthg', 'w', 'h', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', 't', 'e', 'v', 'r', '000', '666']
```

The list started with

```
>>> ['smthg','xyz','random','000','666'][1:3]
['xyz', 'random']
```

but continues growing forever , and the loop never ends for **a growing list**.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, in the code:

```
for anythg in st:
    st[1:3]='whatever'
```

You don't need the loop, because that would just be repeating the same action twice.

```
st[1:3]='whatever'
```

`st[1:3]` means `['xyz', 'random']`. When you assign that to `'whatever'`, it just changes those two variables:

```
['smthg', 'w', 'h', 'a', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r', '000', '666']
```

It replaced `['xyz', 'random']` with `'whatever'`. That's what's causing the behavior that you see.

Comment: Shouldn't it stop after replacing it once?(the cmdln <when asked to display the list 'st'> keeps giving 't','e','v','r' as the output)

Comment: When you write `for anythg in st` it runs as many times as there are elements in st. Since every loop you add more elements to st, it runs forever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) using `enumerate` and check for the indices using if/else

```
st = ['smthg','xyz','random','000','666']

new_st = ['wtevr' if 0 < i < 4 else ele for i, ele in enumerate(st)]
# ['smthg', 'wtevr', 'wtevr', 'wtevr', '666']
```

If you want to stick to your version, you should create a copy of the original list first and then change the elements in the copy

```
st=['smthg','xyz','random','000','666']
new_st = st[:]

for i in range(len(new_st)):
    if 0<i<4:
        new_st[i]='whtevr'
```

Answer (score 0):

When assigning a value to a list slice, it expects the right hand expression to be an iterable. And it then replaces that slice with the iterable. When you try assigning a string, it is treated as a list of characters.

For example,

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l[1:3] = 'abc'
print(l)
# [1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5]
```

In your case, this insertion of `'whtevr'` caused an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

because you are keep changing the list, you are iterating through list and then keep modifying it again and again and iterationg over that list

so in first iteration your list become

```
['smthg', 'w', 'h', 'a', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r', '000', '666']
```

see length of st changes

now for second iteration on above modifed list , it becomes

```
['smthg', 'w', 'h', 'a', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r', '000', '666']
```

again length increase, and so on.. so iterate is not able to reach at end and it 
keep changing and changing and you are reached in that situation
 value of